# On tense: 'realized that the number of something had been increasing'

Tags: expressions, tenses

Why does a sentence like *I realized that the number of cars had been increasing* sound strange?

I googled "realized that the number of * had been increasing", and then I found only three exmples.

But I found a great number of examples like "realized that the number of * had increased".

Why is it impossible to use "past perfect progressive" with *realize* or *find* to refer to the number?

Logically, you can "realize the incremental number".

Comment: Who says it sounds strange?

Comment: Nobody says so. But if it is not strange, how do you explain the google results?

Comment: I get about 5M results in the google for "has been increasing."

Comment: Sorry, deadrat. My mistake. Why is the combination of "realized" and "had been increasing" is uncommon?

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe because it's a very specific locution.

Answer (score 1):

The rarity is probably because when you realize something, it must be due to an event that has occurred. So in order to realize that some number has been increasing, you need to somehow infer at some point in time that the number has been increasing (since some earlier point of time and stretching to beyond the current point of time). It is difficult to do that. This explains why you found many examples with "had increased" rather than "had been increasing", and will also explain rarity with similar verbs like "recognized", all of which express a point in time of the verb occurrence.

In contrast, there are many examples with "said/thought/knew/showed/found that [...] had been increasing", for exactly the same reason, because here there is no point event that is required by the semantics of those verbs.

Comment: I don't see the construction or logic as problematic.  Am I missing something?  If we shift this to the present "I realize that the number has been increasing." it works.

Comment: The past perfect progressive just means that when the speaker made the realization the increase was still happening and relevant.  Are you saying that a realization cannot happen "now" as in "I'm realizing?"

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I'm not saying that it is logically impossible. It is just logically rare. What you said in your second comment is in my answer ("since some earlier point of time and stretching to beyond the current point of time"). It is rarer for verbs like "realize" because they denote a point in time that you grasp the increasing. Your example in your first comment is not simply a shift to present tense, because there "realize" is not a point event unlike "realized". This is why "realize" is easily compatible with "has been increasing".

Comment: @michael_timofeev: For the same reason "You will realize that the number will have been increasing." is logically rare.

Comment: So if I understand you feel that realize is a process and not an event

Comment: What about the second answer that has two past perfects without a reference simple past?

Comment: @michael_timofeev: No I am saying the opposite. "Realize" is not a process, but an achievement (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_aspect). That is why "realized" is not quite incompatible with "that X had been increasing" because the latter tends to denote a period in the past that extends across the point in time of realization. It is not a problem if the progressive does not have duration extending across the point of realization. In your present tense version, "realize" is used with an atelic meaning of "understand", and so is compatible with a progressive crossing the present time.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: But I'm not going to push my analysis because I don't have the tools and corpus resources to substantiate my hypothesis.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: You're welcome. And I realize that I didn't answer one of your questions. Indeed "I am realizing" is invalid because of the lexical aspect of "realize". One has to say "I am beginning to realize" to 'force' a non-telic aspect.

Comment: so if I picture a scene in my imagination that uses the sentence "I am realizing that you have been cheating me." I am using the word in an incorrect sense because it is agreed upon that it is atelic (or telic...I'm still learning this distinction)?  So, it should be "I am beginning to realize that you have been cheating me."

Comment: So knowing a verb's lexical aspect then can be a tool to decide if certain sentences are acceptable or not?  So in my teaching practice, when students ask "Is this ok?" this can be a useful tool?

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Yes we unconsciously learn to use "realize" as a telic (has an end; from "τελος" = "end") verb for the usual meaning and so indeed it has to be "I am beginning/starting to realize that you have been cheating me.". In teaching you probably should explain lexical aspect if students ask. Note that the same word may have some telic meanings and some non-telic meanings. For example "realize" in "I realize that you are tired." has the non-telic meaning of "understand".

Comment: ok, thank you...I need all the tools I can get.  I'm surrounded daily by incorrect grammar and usage and often start questioning whether or not the most basic stuff is correct...for example a student says "I had some classical milk tea with some famous toast at Beijing." (they call a piece of bread, "toast.")

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I'm sure you can get most of your questions answered here. Also "toast" can be a noun referring to toasted bread according to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toast.

Comment: yes, but they called untoasted bread, "toast."  So if they went to Denny's and asked for toast they would be surprised why the bread was crunchy and slightly burnt.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Ohh hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

This is related to perfect continuous past and simple past. 
You'd want to say:

```
I had begun to realize that the number of cars was increasing.
```

Or

```
I had realized that the number of cars had been increasing.
```

---

The second one is more appealing, and closer in meaning to your sentence. The only change being the addition of 'had' before 'realized'. 'Realized' and 'Had realized' (Simple past and past perfect) makes the difference.

Note: The sentence you've mentioned can also be considered correct if it's used in appropriate context (If the context is along the lines of the 'increase in number of cars' action having occurred before your realization, and wasn't an instant observation you had made in the past).

Comment: Is it possible to put two past perfect verbs in a sentence without a simple past reference point?

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that the number of cars had been increasing.

Let's recast this sentence into the present:

> I realize that the number of cars has been increasing.

That would be more common than the original past tense/past perfect version.

I will try to imagine some context for the sentence that felt strange to you.  Suppose you go to a local government public meeting on June 1st where some traffic problem is being discussed.  As part of the discussion, you might say, *I realize that the number of cars has been increasing, but I wasn't aware that ....*

Now let's allow some time to go by.  One day you are telling a friend how your views on that traffic topic have evolved.  You might say, *I realized that the number of cars had been increasing, but then in early June I learned that ....*

I had to work pretty hard to build a story around your strange sentence... but I think I got it to work.